# Using XSLT to recursively load relative XML files and apply transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file whose structure looks like this:

```
<root>
<includes>
    <includeFile name="../other/some_xml.xml"/>
</includes> 
<itemlist>  
        <item id="1" >
            <selections>
                <selection name="one" />
            </selections>
        </item>
</itemlist>
```

The xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="ItemList">
            <xsl:if test="root/item">
                <xsl:call-template name="templ" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="templ">
        <xsl:element name="ItemList">
            <xsl:for-each select="root/itemlist/item">

                <xsl:element name="Item">
                    <xsl:element name="ItemIdentifier">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Condition">
                        <xsl:value-of select="selections/selection[1]/@name" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I created one XSLT which i am using to filter out items. The problem is that for every file, i have to check if it contains the includefile tag, which is a relative path pointing to a similar xml, and if it does, i need to collect items from that file also, **recursively**. For now i transformed the xml using my xslt and then i have to parse the xml to look for includefile tag. This solution doesn't look elegant and i was wondering if all of it could be done via xslt.

Comment: Please show _all_ of the code, the whole stylesheet (specifically, the named template called `templ`) - and all inputs that are relevant to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @David Make your edits as substantial as possible - fix _everything_, not just about enough characters to submit the suggested edit and get 2 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT `document` function in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0 additionally the `doc` function allow you to pull in further documents, processing is then simply possible with matching templates. So consider to move your XSLT coding style to write matching templates and apply-templates, then you can easily do

```
<xsl:template match="includes/includeFile">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/*"/>
<xsl:template>
```

and then you simply need to make sure the `<xsl:template match="root">...</xsl:template>` creates the output you want.