# Can i collect elements in <xsl:variable>, while recursively parsing XML files, to transform them later

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a few xml files with a structure like this:

**1.xml**

```
  <root>
<includeFile name="2.xml" />
<a>
    <items>
        <item id="1" />
        <item id="2" />
    </items>
    <items>
        <item id="3" />
        <item id="4" />
        <item id="5" />
    </items>
</a>
<b>
    <items>
        <item id="6" />
        <item id="7" />
    </items>
    <items>
        <item id="8" />
    </items>
</b>
<c>
    <items>
        <item id="9" />
        <item id="10" />
    </items>
</c>
```

All the tags a, b and c are optional. I have to parse a file for items, and then recursively parse the file specified in include tag. I am trying to get all these items into a single file under their respective parents(a, b and c) with the help of XSLT. I can get all the elements from all the files but my problem is that i am unable to combine them under single parent tags. I tried using  but they don't seem to be able to solve my prob. My XSLT looks like this (this one is incomplete)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="fileTemp" />
        <xsl:for-each select="root/includeFile">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="mi" />
    <xsl:template name="fileTemp">
                <xsl:variable name="mi" select="root/items" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can i collect all items into a variable or something within XSLT while i parse different XMLs and then apply my transformations on it ?

For eg: parsing 1.xml, which will include 2.xml as

```
    <root>
<a>
    <items>
        <item id="100" />
        <item id="200" />
    </items>
</a>
<b>
    <items>
        <item id="80" />
    </items>
</b>
<c>
    <items>
        <item id="90" />
    </items>
</c>
```

...should produce

```
    <root>
<a>
    <items>
        <item id="1" />
        <item id="2" />
    </items>
    <items>
        <item id="3" />
        <item id="4" />
        <item id="5" />
    </items>
     <items>
        <item id="100" />
        <item id="200" />
    </items>
</a>
<b>
    <items>
        <item id="6" />
        <item id="7" />
    </items>
    <items>
        <item id="8" />
    </items>
    <items>
        <item id="80" />
    </items>
</b>
<c>
    <items>
        <item id="9" />
        <item id="" />
    </items>
    <items>
        <item id="90" />
    </items>
</c>
</root>
```

Comment: Before asking new questions, please accept or otherwise respond to the [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28748668/1987598).

Comment: Consider to show us the result structure you want for three or four input sample mockups.

Comment: Your stylesheet claims to be XSLT 2.0, but then you use a Xalan-specific extension in the `xsl:output`, and Xalan only implements XSLT 1.0.  Which processor are you actually using here?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet (to be used with Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or any other XSLT 2.0 processor) which uses a recursive function to collect the various items from the referenced documents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:collect" as="element()*">
  <xsl:param name="docs" as="document-node()*"/>

  <xsl:sequence select="$docs/*/a, $docs/*/b, $docs/*/c"/>

  <xsl:variable name="included-docs" as="document-node()*" select="document($docs/*/includeFile/@name)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="if (exists($included-docs)) then mf:collect($included-docs) else ()"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:variable name="collected-items" select="mf:collect(/)"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <a>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$collected-items[self::a]/items"/>
    </a>
    <b>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$collected-items[self::b]/items"/>
    </b>
    <c>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$collected-items[self::c]/items"/>
    </c>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To to the same with XSLT 1.0 you would need to write a recursive template to construct a result tree fragment and then you need to use `exsl:node-set` or similar to be able to select and output the various items from the result tree fragment